# Javascript: Using an External Library

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script that requires performing arithmetic operations on very large integers (encryption algorithm) and so I am trying to use an external library (https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/tree/master). However, when I add the src attribute to the script tag, I get an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: buttonClick is not defined" even though my buttonClick() function is clearly defined. I need to use this library and I'm not sure what to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://peterolson.github.com/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js">
...
<button type="button" onclick="buttonClick()">Encrypt</button>
...
function buttonClick(){
        plaintext = document.getElementById("plaintext").value;
        plaintextLength = plaintext.length;
        plaintextNum = [];
        plaintextNumString = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < plaintextLength; i++){
            plaintextNum[i] = plaintext.charCodeAt(i);
            plaintextNumString += plaintextNum[i];
        }

        plaintextNumInt = bigInt(parseInt(plaintextNumString));
        //ciphertextNumInt = bigInt((Math.pow(plaintextNumInt, e))%n);
        ciphertextNumInt = plaintextNumInt.modPow(e, n);

        console.log(plaintextNumInt + " " + plaintextNum[2] + " " + ciphertextNumInt + " " + n + " " + plaintext);

        document.getElementById("ciphertext").innerHTML = ciphertextNumInt;
    }
```

Comment: Could you put your code in a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Did you wrap your own javascript code into a script tag either?

Comment: We can't really help you if you provide an incomplete example. See [mcve] for guidance. @Quentin: I don't think that's the right duplicate (or at least I'm not able to see why it should be).

Comment: Have you tried placing the script tag at the end of the `</body>` instead?

Comment: @FelixKling — Adding a src attribute to the (existing) script tag (presumably containing the function definition) broke it.

Comment: @bruh — No. There's no attempt to access the function before the button is actually clicked.

Comment: @Quentin you seem to assume that all the content is inside a single script element. But that would mean the button element is inside the script element as well. However, based on the description you might be right. The code example is messed up.